# Hall and Knight- Higher Algebra Problem 23, Example V. b

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-progressions

If $r < 1$ and positive and m is a positive integer,  show that $(2m+1)r^m(1-r)<1-r^{2m+1}$. Hence show that $nr^n$ is indefinitely small when $n$ is indefinitely great.

I have tried by taking $\frac{1-r^{2m+1}}{1-r}$ as the sum of the series $1 + r + r^2 ... + r^{2m}$ and then we may try to prove that $(2m+1)r^m > 1 + r + r^2 ... + r^{2m}$.

I have proved the inequality but am unable to prove the limit. The solution book says something which I do not understand. The solution given is

$(2m+1)r^m(1-r)<1-r^{2m+1}$

(multiplying by $r^{m+1}$ on both sides)

$=>(2m+1)r^{2m+1}(1-r)<r^{m+1}(1-r^{2m+1})$

putting $n=2m+1$

$=>nr^n(1-r)<r^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(1-r^{n})$

this much I understand but then it says that if $n$ is made indefinitely great, then $r^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ becomes indefinitely small and $nr^n$ becomes indefinitely small.

Comment: what are your attempts?

Comment: While this is undoubtedly an interesting problem, it would improve the Question if you added some context to the bare problem statement.  For example, why do find this problem interesting?  What approach is suggested by the surrounding course materials?  Above all, what specific difficulty did you encounter in trying this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

If $0<r<1$, then $1>r>r^2>r^3>\dots$ and 
$$1-r^{2m+1}=(1-r)(1+r+r^2+\dots+r^{2m}).$$

Comment: I think it is premature to post this "hint" before the OP has identified where they have difficulty.  You have not even clarified where you think this rather well-known factorization (already hinted at in the tag "geometric progressions") will help in solving the problem (in showing the inequality? or in showing the "indefinitely small" limit?).

Comment: In showing the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1 - r^{2m+1}}{1-r}&= 1+r+ \dots +r^{2m}\\
&= r^m(\frac{1}{r^m} + \frac{1}{r^{m-1}} + \dots + \frac{1}{r} + 1+ r +r^2 + \dots + r^{m-1}+r^m)\\
&= r^m[1 + (r^m+\frac{1}{r^m}) + (r^{m-1} + \frac{1}{r^{m-1}}) + \dots +(r + \frac{1}{r})]\\
&> r^m(1 + \underbrace{2 + \dots + 2}_{m \text{ times}}) = (2m + 1)r^m
\end{aligned}$$

because for $0<x<1$ you have $x + \frac{1}{x} >2$.

Comment: Thanks. But why is the last one x + 1/x > 2

Comment: Define $f(x)=x+1/x$ and study the real function $f$. Derivative is...

Comment: But the book says no u8se of calculus

Comment: Then $x+1/x -2 = (\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^2 \ge 0$

Comment: Thank you. How to do the $nr^n$ indefinitely great?